# Le verbe ausculter

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, étymologie, histoire

In the Romanian language the verb **a asculta** means *to listen, to hear*. E.g.

> Ascultă-mă acuma=Listen to me now.

According to [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asculta)

> ...From Vulgar Latin *ascultāre, from Latin auscultāre, present active infinitive of auscultō (“I listen”). Doublet of ausculta, a borrowing.

In the French language there is the verb  ausculter meaning *Écouter les sons produits à l'intérieur du corps à l'oreille ou à l'aide d'un stéthoscope.* I am wondering how ausculter (Terme de chancellerie romaine. Écouter et accueillir, after Littré) has obtained its particular (medical) meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Terme de chancellerie romaine. Écouter et accueillir" you found in *Littré* is misleading (I won't say wrong but the least one can say is that it is taking (very short) short-cuts).

The verb *auscultare* in Latin meant "to listen secretly, to spy" (Gaffiot and [online Latin dictionary](http://www.dicolatin.com/FR/LAK/0/AUSCULTARE/index.htm)) and "to obey" (which is only a derivative meaning since in order "to obey" one has first "to listen carefully" to what they are told).

In Late Latin it came to mean "to compare"<sup>1</sup> » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*) and that was the only meaning that remained in Old French (see [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/auscu)).

It was only in the 19th century that the word was used by the medical profession. [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ausculter):

> 1<sup>re</sup> attest. dans la lexicogr. : *1832* (F. Raymond, *Dict. gén. de la lang. fr*., Paris, Pitois-Levrault et Cie, t. 1), mais prob. empl. auparavant par **Laennec** (v. *auscultation*) qui, cependant, ne l'emploie pas dans son *Traité de l'auscultation médiate*; 1856 fig., supra ex. 4. 1 empr. au lat. médiév. auscultare au sens jur. « comparer, confronter » (1270, Chartae Carinthiae, V, 35 ds Mittellat. W. s.v., 1267, 66); 2 empr. au lat. class. *auscultare* « prêter l'oreille, écouter attentivement » [d'où la spécialisation méd. du terme] (Plaute, Amph., 1006 ds TLL s.v., 1534, 66).

The [DHELL](http://www.dhell.paris-sorbonne.fr/dictionnaire:auscultare7#fn__5) (*Dictionnaire Historique et Encyclopédie Linguistique du Latin*) interestingly  compares the evolution of the latin words *auscultare* and  *audire* (which gave [*ouïr*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ouir) in French).

> Lat. *auscultare*, comme terme exprimant l’« **attention auditive**<sup>2</sup> », occupe la position ‘non résultative’ par rapport à *audire*, qui exprime la « perception effective ». Or, au cours de la latinité, *auscultare* ne cesse de progresser vers cette dernière valeur*, jusqu’à régir des compléments faisant référence non seulement à la source d’émission (*auscultare aliquem qui dicit*), mais aussi au message lui-même (*auscultare quod dicit*). Ce déplacement s’accélère dans les langues romanes, spécialement en français, à cause de la disparition de *ouïr*, dont la faible expression, sujette à des homonymies, demandait le remplacement.

*Ausculter* can also be used nowadays in a figurative sense to mean "to examine carefully", so not only used for a close examination of the human body.

---

<sup>1</sup> How it evolved to that meaning could be a question for [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/). Although I presume that in order to compare anything you have to examine them very carefully (even if it can be by looking at it as well as  by listening to it).
<sup>2</sup> My emphasis.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!  It makes all the more sense because" auscultare" is a compound derived from "aus" and "clutare" where" aus" is related to "auris" - "ear".

Answer (score 1):

It's the specific sense "listen intently" that was borrowed by the medical profession sometime in the 16th century ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ausculter)). At the time, doctors had a notorious tendency to heavily use (one might say abuse) Greek and Latin terms. This was heavily mocked, most famously by Molière (*Le Malade Imaginaire*), but also by Shakespeare (e.g. Caius in *The Merry Wives of Windsor*). Traces of it remain in various aspect of medical French, e.g. "[anamnèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamn%C3%A8se_(m%C3%A9decine))" ("medical history").

Comment: Je lis l'article du TLFi comme indiquant que le sens médical d'ausculter remonte à Laennec, l'inventeur du stéthoscope, et pas au 16e siècle.

Comment: @petitrien Tout à fait. Confirmé par d'autres sources et en particulier le DHLF.  Laennec n'a pas employé *ausculter* lui-même mais a remis le substantif *auscultation* dans son sens original  en l'employant dans son [Traité de l'auscultation médiate](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97402610.texteImage) et des maladies des poumons et du cœur.

Comment: TLFi dit "première attestation *dans la lexicographie*", c'est-à-dire dans un dictionnaire.

Comment: @Circeus TLF dit "1re attest. dans la lexicogr. : **1832**"  pour le **sens 2** (le seul que tu mentionnes). Et pour le **sens 1. : "1510-41** latinisme « examiner, collationner, confronter »".